# Метод .ready()

Tags: jquery, dom

Все знают такой метод или пользуются им

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//что делать после того как DOM готов
});
```

Но что делать если DOM будет изменяться входе действий на странице (погрузка новых данных например).

Они же не будут учитываться и все что внутри этого метода не будет реагировать на новые элементы?

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: если вешать события типа click/focus, то on с селектором:

    $(parent).on(event,childselector,handler);

если нужна постобработка - делать ее в callback загрузчика.

Comment: @eicto можно поподробней о "постобработкe" ? в чем суть?

Comment: что вы делаете в ready ? постобработка - например навешать каких нить элементов итд...

Comment: я что-то не совсем понял. наверное из-за того что целый день потратил на решение задачи.. есть пример ? или статья?? буду благодарен

Comment: не могу вам помочь, слишком мало данных о вашей проблеме. пример простой

    $.get(url,function(data) {/*здесь появляются новые элементы, здесь же навешиваем на них события и что-вы-там-ещё делаете в $(function(){}) */ } );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут простейший алгоритм. Для примера будем добавлять классы.

1. Пишем функцию, которая например всем инпутам без класса myclass должна его добавить.
2. Вызываем её в .ready
3. Вызываем её при изменении дом дерева.

Comment: Но она будет выполняться так 2 раза что недопустимо.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // встроим перехватчик события на вставку новых элементов на страницу
  $('body').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
     alert($(event.target).html());
  });
```

Comment: >[ Deprecated This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FMutation_events)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver